# Pyplot divide X scale axis by number

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have this code which plots curves on x and y axis defined by an array u

```
titulo = "lambda=0.5   M=200   N=10"

M = 200
N = 10
u = calcula_u_a1(M,N)


for i in range (0, M+1, int(M*0.1)):
#     if i == 0 or i == round(0.1*M) or i == round(0.2*M) or i == round(0.3*M) or i == round(0.4*M) or i == round(0.5*M):
    plt.plot(u[i], label= "t=" + str(i/M))
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title(titulo)
    plt.xlabel('Distancia')
    plt.ylabel('Temperatura')



plt.show()
```

[image]

What I need to do is divide the x scale, so instead of [0, ..., 10] it would be [0, ..., 1] (divide x scale by N)

Anyway of doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `plt.plot` function can take x and y coordinates as input. At the moment, you just provide the y coordinates in the `u[i]` variable. Try `plt.plot(numpy.linspace(0, 1, len(u[i])), u[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved it another way, i created a linearspace and made it my X axis:

```
titulo = "lambda=0.5   M=800   N=20"
M = 800
N = 20
X = np.linspace(0, 1, N+1)
u = calcula_u_a1(M,N)

for i in range (0, M+1, int(M*0.1)):
   plt.plot(X, u[i], label= "t=" + str(i/M))
   plt.legend(loc='best')
   plt.title(titulo)
   plt.xlabel('Distancia')
   plt.ylabel('Temperatura')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Remember to remove everything but plt.plot() from the loop! Legend, title and labels don;t need to be applied for every plotted line, just oncefor the entire graph!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the xticks to look like you need them!

I also took the plot titling and labeling out of the loop as you don't need to assign it for every plotted line but just once for the entire figure/subplot!

```
titulo = "lambda=0.5   M=200   N=10"

M = 200
N = 10
u = calcula_u_a1(M,N)

# Added to be able to manipulate easly XTicks of the plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

for i in range (0, M+1, int(M*0.1)):
#     if i == 0 or i == round(0.1*M) or i == round(0.2*M) or i == round(0.3*M) or i == round(0.4*M) or i == round(0.5*M):
    ax.plot(u[i], label= "t=" + str(i/M))

# Ticks are placed at positions 0 to 10 but the values displayed are from 0 to 1
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 11, 1))
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(np.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1).round(1))

# Moved these out of the loop
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title(titulo)
plt.xlabel('Distancia')
plt.ylabel('Temperatura')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why are you changing the y ticks?

Comment: Thanks man, it almost works as i needed, but the x axis became unreadable, with a lot of 0`s

Comment: @Sheldore Because I used bits of my code... Damn, thanks for letting me now, edited

Comment: @IltonAndrew can you show me what you're getting now? Maybe I can edit my answer to make it look more usable! Also how dense should the ticks be? If I understood correctly you wanted to have 0->1 instead of 0->10 but I have no idea of how many steps you wanted to visualize

Comment: @IltonAndrew I made it readable, added a .round(1) method to the tick labels, let me know if this solved your previous issue! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the set of x values (from 0 to 1 adding by 0.1) :

```
delta = 0.1
distancia = np.arange(0, 1 + delta, delta)
```

then plot :

```
plt.plot(distancia, u[i], label= "t=" + str(i/M))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.title(titulo)
plt.xlabel('Distancia')
plt.ylabel('Temperatura')
plt.show()
```

Or if inside a loop :

```
plt.plot(distancia[i], u[i], label= "t=" + str(i/M))
```